# Generating a Spectrogram/FFT using React JS library using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fft, frequency, spectrogram

I have been going through many repositories but could not find anything to start with.
Currently in need of a javascript based ReactJS spectrogram/fft generator using computer microphone.

Will share a link for the spectrogram down below but using typescript.
https://github.com/calebj0seph/spectro

Will share a link for the fft down below.
https://arachnoid.com/SigGen/index.html

Any help getting this done in ReactJS javascript would be much appreciated.